# Query with string date format in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data like below in my mongoDB collection. I want to count the total number or search_term on today basis.

```
_id:ObjectId("5b7e1d38981cdc1a7c8bb5fc")
search_term:"Baiyoke Boutique"
date:"August 23rd 2018, 9:34:32 am"

_id:ObjectId("5b7e1fa8fa27fd2754080ad9")
search_term:"Baiyoke Boutique"
date:"August 23rd 2018, 9:44:56 am"

_id:ObjectId("5b7e28314d2d0f388c1596cd")
search_term:"Baiyoke Florting Market"
date:"August 23rd 2018, 10:21:21 am"
```

I have tried following query. I have used moment. I am not what mistake I did.

```
var start = moment().startOf('day');
var end = moment().endOf('day');

history.find({
    date: {
        $gte: start,
        $lt: end
    }
    }).count().toArray(
    function (e, res) {
        if (e) callback(e)
        else callback(null, res)
});
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: I get history.find(...).count(...).toArray is not a function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try below queries in mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gte": [{ "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$date" }}, start.toDate() ],
    "$lt": [{ "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$date" }}, end.toDate() ]
  }
}).count()
```

or with aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "date": {
      "$dateFromString": {
        "dateString": "$date"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": start.toDate(), "$lt": end.toDate() }}},
  { "$count": "count" }
])
```

Comment: Hi @Ashh. Can you please help me. if my collection column have date="2020-12-13 17:20:00" and I want to fetch record greater than my current datetime which is "2020-12-11 00:00:00". how I can write expr in find()?

Comment: @NaisargParmar Pls ask a new question i will definitely try to help

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
db.col.aggregate([{$addFields: {
      convertedDate: { $toDate: "$date" }
   }},
   {"$match" : 
       {"convertedDate" : 
           {"$gte" : ISODate("2018-08-23T09:34:32.000Z"),
            "$lte" : ISODate("2018-08-23T09:34:32.000Z")}
        }
    },
    {"$group" : {"_id" : null,"count" : {"$sum" : 1}}},
    {"$project" : {"_id" : 0}}
   ])
```

This is for Node js

```
var start = moment().startOf('day');
var end = moment().endOf('day');

history.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        convertedDate: { $toDate: "$date" }
    }
},
{
    "$match":
    {
        "convertedDate":
        {
            "$gte": start,
            "$lte": end
        }
    }
},
{ "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
{ "$project": { "_id": 0 } }
], function (err, count) {
    console.log(count)
})
```

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: AggregationCursor {
  pool: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler:
   Store {
     s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: BSON {},
  ns: 'ogin-test.history',
  cmd:
   { aggregate: 'history',
     pipeline: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     cursor: {} },
  options:
   { readPreference: ReadPreference { mode: 'primary', tags: undefined },

Comment: This code is working fine for me and $toDate supports mongo version 4+

Comment: my mongodb version is 3.6.4

Comment: Should be better `var start = moment().startOf('day').toDate();` and `var end = moment().endOf('day').toDate();`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
history.count({date: {
    $gte: start,
    $lt: end
}}, function( err, count){
    console.log( "Number of users:", count );
})
```

for native mongodb driver

```
db.collection(collectionName).count({}, function(error, numOfDocs){
    if(error) return callback(error);
    db.close();
    callback(null, numOfDocs);
});
```

Comment: the result is coming 0 .. it should give 3 according to above example data set

Comment: How do you insert your date? String or date?

Comment: wrap start and end with ISODate -- {date: {
    $gte: ISODate(start),
    $lt: ISODate(end)
}

Answer (score -1):

You are storing the string representation of the date. Try calling `toDate()` on moment object before storing into the database

Comment: It is not necessary if you want to keep the JSON a compatible. You can get the benefits 
 of using an EJSON Date object by formatting the data as ISO8601 with your validation. `{"lastAccess": { $gt: "2021-08-01T00:00:00.000Z }}"` will work. The OP is using ObjectID, so that doesn't seem to be his goal, so obviously something is wrong with the design.