# Mongoose find by date in array of objects string date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to to build a mongoose query to find records that match one date, i think its working but it doesn't show anything because the date i have in my array of objects is string and i am using date to compare them.

```
const startDate = new Date(new Date(req.query.date).setHours(0, 0, 0));
const endDate = new Date(new Date(req.query.date).setHours(23, 59, 59));
const transactions = await Transaction.paginate({ 'payments.date': { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate } }, { allowDiskUse: true, page: req.query.page });
```

Here's the schema for payments object

```
payments: [
    {
        payment_system: {
            type: String,
        },
        amount: {
            type: Number,
        },
        date: {
            index: true,
            type: String,
        },
    },
],
```

As you can see the date is string, and its indexed. The reason i put it as a string because it would keep the server time instead of the timezone i desired. But that's not the problem the problem is to filter these results by date which is string. Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984693/11283638

Comment: I would recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), then it would be `startDate = moment().startOf('day').toDate()` and `endDate = moment().endOf('day').toDate()`

Comment: @Ashutoshpatole just tried that but i am getting an error `An object representing an expression must have exactly one field:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example

```
const startDate = moment(req.query.createdDate).startOf('day');
const endDate = moment(req.query.createdDate).endOf('day');
const transactions = await Transaction.paginate(
        {
            'payments.date': {
                $gte: startDate.toDate().toISOString(),
                $lt: endDate.toDate().toISOString(),
            },
        },
        { allowDiskUse: true, page: req.query.page }
    );
```

Following code works fine for me, in combination with `mongoose-v2-paginate`.
Works if you have string timestamps.